# How to use oracle REGEXP_LIKE() in querydsl?

Tags: java, oracle, querydsl

I want to search string in Oracle db with diacritic, for i.e: input "o" then search "o" as well as "o", "ö" or "ô".
I can do it with the REGEXP_LIKE() function in native SQL with the Base Letter Operator [==] as following:

```
where REGEXP_LIKE(<column_name>,'[[=o=]]')
```

However, now, I dont know how to do it with QueryDSL. I tried the solution @https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1713 but it's not successful.

The current code is as following:

```
return new JPAQuery<AEntity>(em)
            .from(QAEntity.aEntity)
            .where(Expressions.booleanTemplate("REGEXP_LIKE({0}, {1})", QAEntity.aEntity.name, "[[=o=]]"))
            .orderBy(QAEntity.aEntity.name.asc())
            .fetch();
```

It throws exception like that:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 3, column 18 [select aEntity
from domain.AEntity aEntity
where REGEXP_LIKE(aEntity.name, ?1)
order by aEntity.name asc]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    ... 123 common frames omitted
```

Can anybody please suggest some idea?

Answer (score 2):

You forget quotes near `{1}`

it should be like

```
return new JPAQuery<AEntity>(em)
            .from(QAEntity.aEntity)
            .where(Expressions.booleanTemplate("REGEXP_LIKE({0}, '{1}')", QAEntity.aEntity.name, "[[=o=]]"))
            .orderBy(QAEntity.aEntity.name.asc())
            .fetch();
```

EDIT.  I found that if you need to use `regexp_like` you should specify next

```
(Expressions.booleanTemplate
                ("function('REGEXP_LIKE', {0}, {1})", QAEntity.aEntity.name, "[[=o=]]"))
```

Comment: thanks @MichaelPiankov, I tried but the error is still the same

Comment: I make mistake @doannx. THank you. I add correct answer.

Comment: I tried with your edit, unfortunately, the error still comes as following   `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: function (REGEXP_LIKE) near line 3, column 7 [select aEntity
from domain.AEntity aEntity
where function('REGEXP_LIKE', aEntity.name, ?1)
order by aEntity.name asc]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)...`

Answer (score 0):

For those who are in the same problem: my final solution is configuring the DB & server (in my case is JBoss) to support linguitics search, then, no need to change my code.